# Is there a way to see casual rank of other players like you can see ping as numbers instead of bars?

Tags: team-fortress-2

All you can see is these badges/medals and it's not clear from the colors what the number of Tiers they have is. The advanced menu has an option to change how the scoreboard displays ping of all players from vague bars to actual millisecond numbers. Is there a similar setting for rank badges?

Answer (score 3):

Tiers in the scoreboard have been bugged since the release. There is no setting to change it. It's simply a bug that the team haven't fixed yet. Keep an eye out on the updates for now to spot any changes that introduce this.

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/1697169163404641010/) (for the longevity of bug):